# Viewing registers in ViEmu

Tags: visual-studio, vim, viemu

I am using the ViEmu extension for Visual Studio 2015. In Vim I can view the content of registers with `:registers` or `:reg`. In ViEmu this returns "Unknown command".

How can the registers be viewed in ViEmu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:reg` or `:registers` is a vim extension not found in vi.  The [ViEmu documentation](http://www.viemu.com/viemu_doc.html) does not mention this extension.  The [*General*](http://www.viemu.com/viemu_doc.html#general) section (essentially a summary of changes) makes it plain that ViEmu does not have *all* of vim's features.

Lacking that, the only way you can "see" a register contents would be to temporarily *put* it into the current buffer.

Comment: I am afraid that is indeed the case. Would be a nice feature. Thank you for your answer.